# Set attribute of class from Dict with cast

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, casting, setattribute

I'm trying to parse a Dict of [str,str] with key value pair into a object (class).
The first contains the name of attributes and the second the value.

ex: `[('CLIENT_ID','123456'), ('AUTO_COMMIT', 'False'), ('BROKER_URL', 'http://foo.bar')]`

The code to parse is the next:

```py
class KafkaSettings():
    BROKER_URL: str = None
    CLIENT_ID: str = None
    AUTO_COMMIT: bool = False

    def __init__(self, d: Dict[str, str]):
        if d is not None:
            for key, value in d.items():
                attr = self.__getattribute__(key)
                casted_value = cast(attr, value)
                self.__setattr__(key, casted_value)
```

The parser works but the type of the value is altered. For example, **AUTO_COMMIT** attr as type *bool* but with `setattr` the type changed into *str*. The cast of the value into the good type not work.
I don't know the Python language.

How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: where/how is `cast()` defined?

Comment: Into the for loop

Comment: `self.__getattribute__` is overkill. Just use `getattr(self, key)`.

Comment: What is `cast`? If you are referring to `typing.cast`, it doesn't do anything except return its second argument as-is. `cast` is only meant to guide a type checker like `mypy`.

Comment: If you want to convert a string like `'False'` to `False`, you need to do that yourself explicitly.

Comment: Type hints are just that: *hints* for a type checker. They don't have any effect on runtime behavior.

Comment: Is no way to detect the type and convert in the type detected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using below code,

```
from typing import Dict


class KafkaSettings():
    BROKER_URL: str = None
    CLIENT_ID: str = None
    AUTO_COMMIT: bool = False

    def __init__(self, d: Dict[str, str]):
        if d is not None:
            for key, value in d.items():
                attr = self.__getattribute__(key)
                
                # change as follows
                if key == "AUTO_COMMIT":
                    value = bool(value)

                self.__setattr__(key, value)
```

You can solve this issue by checking the `key` and if it is equal to `AUTO_COMMIT` then you can cast the `string` value to the `bool` value by using `bool()` method.

But note that this is a specific solution for your code. So it is better to add the values with their actual `type` (as you needed) when making the `dictionary`. Then you do not need any casting.

For an example, In this case, you can use this,

`[('CLIENT_ID','123456'), ('AUTO_COMMIT', False), ('BROKER_URL', 'http://foo.bar')]`

(store `False` as boolean instead of string)

instead of this,

`[('CLIENT_ID','123456'), ('AUTO_COMMIT', 'False'), ('BROKER_URL', 'http://foo.bar')]`

Comment: Is it possible `  if key == "AUTO_COMMIT":` to have a condition with if the value is a boolean ?

Comment: Did you mean like `if value == "False" or value == "True":`? If so, Yes we can code that way. If you are using that approach you can use the `eval()` method to take the actual value of the string. Then the if condition should change as follows, `if type(eval(value)) == bool:` the code should change accordingly. If you need to know further I can add the answer in that way also.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard [pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic) elevator pitch.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class KafkaSettings(BaseModel):
    BROKER_URL: str = None
    CLIENT_ID: str = None
    AUTO_COMMIT: bool = False

    @classmethod 
    def factory(cls, tuples):
        di = {v[0]:v[1] for v in tuples}
        return KafkaSettings(**di)
    
print(KafkaSettings.factory([('CLIENT_ID','123456'), ('AUTO_COMMIT', 'False'), ('BROKER_URL', 'http://foo.bar')]))
```

##### output:

```
BROKER_URL='http://foo.bar' CLIENT_ID='123456' AUTO_COMMIT=False
```

Btw, pydantic supports multiple types and the order makes a difference `"3"` => `foo : str|int` => `"3"`  while `"3"` => `foo : int|str` => `3` , IIRC.

And `('AUTO_COMMIT', '1')` => `True`.

And here's a more troubleshooting-friendly version of the factory:

```
    @classmethod 
    def factory(cls, tuples):
        try:
            print(f"{tuples=}")
            di = {v[0]:v[1] for v in tuples}
            print(f"{di=}")
            res = KafkaSettings(**di)
            return res
            #pragma: no cover pylint: disable=unused-variable
        except (Exception,) as e: 
            print(f"{e=}")
            breakpoint()
            raise
```

Comment: I have the following error 
`@classmethod
    def factory(cls, tuples):
        di = {v[0]:v[1] for v in tuples}
>       return KafkaSettings(**di)
E       TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'K'
`

Comment: Can you print out what is in `di` before you send it in?  I did run this code and got the output from the printout.  Looks to me you have a `K` key in that dict somehow.  But actually pydantic's normal behavior is to ignore keys that dont match the class annotations, so even a K would get dropped.  You sure you copied code exactly as is?  I've just repasted into a different file, from here, and it worked fine.  Python 3.10, pydantic  1.10.4.

Comment: I retried differently and pydantic returns the values. Thanks.
I used Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform automatic conversion of a value to another type using type hints. You need to be explicit. For example (and fixing your attempts to extract type information from the variable annotations):

```
class KafkaSettings():
    BROKER_URL: str = None
    CLIENT_ID: str = None
    AUTO_COMMIT: bool = False

    def __init__(self, d: Dict[str, str]):
        for key, value in d.items():
            if issubclass(KafkaSettings.__annotations__[key], bool):
                casted_value = {'True': True, 'False': False}[value]
            else:
                casted_value = value

            setattr(self, key, casted_value)
```

What you really want is something more explicit, and divide `__init__` into a simpler `__init__` and a class method. (The simpler `__init__` can be autogenerated by `dataclasses.dataclass`.)

```
# Enhance as you like
bool_map = {
    'False': False,
    'True': True,
    'F': False,
    'T': True,
    'yes': True,
    'no': False,
}
    
@dataclass
class KafkaSettings:
    broker_url: str = None
    client_id: str = None
    auto_commit: bool = False

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: Dict[str, str]):
        url = d.get('BROKER_URL')
        client_id = d.get('CLIENT_ID')
        autocommit_str = d.get('AUTO_COMMIT')
        if autocommit_str is None:
            autocommit = False
        else:
            autocommit = bool_map[autocommit_str]

        return cls(url, client_id, autocommit)
```

Using a dictionary is *a* way to provide values for the attribute, but it is not fundamentally necessary. What you *need* to instantiate `KafkaSettings` are two strings and a boolean value: supply those directly to `__init__`, and define the class method to extract them from a dictionary.

Comment: I would have preferred not to define all the attributes but if that's the only way we can do why not. I'll test your solution.